# Django HTTP Response object for GAE Cron

Tags: django, google-app-engine, cron, httpresponse

I am doing this using Django / GAE / Python environment:

```
cron:
    #run events every 12 hours
```

and

```
def events(request):
    # read all records 
    # Do some processing on a few records

   return http.HTTPResponseGone('Some Records are modified' )
```

Result in production :
    Job runs on time with 'failed' message
    However, it has done the job exactly on the datastore as required
    No error log entry seen 
Dev : No errors ; returns the message 'Some Records are modified'

Is it possible to avoid HTTP Response returned ? There is no need for HTTPResponse for me, however, I have kept this as Dev server testing fails in its absence. Can some one
help me to make the code clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gone is error 410.  You should return 200 Success if the operation succeeds.  When you return [`HttpResponse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/), the default status is 200.

Comment: Is it possible to completely remove the return statement. In a cron job, it is not making any sense. I have kept this for the sake of matching with request ?

Comment: @Sharma, App Engine cron jobs are just HTTP requests, and every HTTP request needs a HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the change I need to make would be return http.HTTPResponse(). Will give a try and see what happen in production